# How to adjust 'frozen' venturi tube in stove?

Tags: gas, stove, natural-gas, propane, orifice

We are installing a gas to propane conversion kit for a stove. We've changed the orifice (left brass part in photo) but we also need to adjust the position of the venturi tube (marked with arrow) - but can't get it to move.

The tube is held in place with a setscrew which has been loosened. But the tube still does not want to move at all.

It is awkward to grip and this might be the main problem, or perhaps it is frozen in place by crud or corrosion, although most of the stove is NOT particularly corroded. That said, we did have one other setscrew break off, so... perhaps.

I'm looking for recommendations on how to free it up and slide it. It needs to move outwards something like 1/8 - 1/4 inch (ie a few mm). There is supposed to be an embossed mark indicating where to position it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grip it with a pair of pliers and wiggle/torque it up and down. Also try to heat it with a torch or a hot air gun and without letting it cool douse it with cold water.
This causes expansion and contraction in different places and can free up components.

Comment: Heat may be the answer... it seems like these were originally meant to move freely when the screw is undone. But it is very awkward due to the surrounding parts to get an tools on there with more than a tiny contact patch...